# How to access the Outlook server (to sent sms) from SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, outlook, smtp, ssis-2012

How to access the Outlook server to sent  email using SSIS.There is an email account ,which can be used to sms to any mobile number using outlook server.when try to use the smtp server to send sms it gives an error

```
[Send Mail Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay".
```

so,planning to use outlook server instead of smtp.

It seems, Smtp is not allowing the email  account(from) to send email/sms to a domain other than internal addresses!?. Though this works perfectly fine with the outlook server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the email address for the phone number; For example my number on AT&T in USA is read more like 123456789@text.att.net. You should have something similar and you wont have to worry about SMTP or any other setting.